# Calling a nested function from global scope

Tags: javascript, typeerror, p5.js, nested-function

So, i have the following code:

```
this.balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  noStroke();
  balls.push(new Ball(width / 2, height / 2, 20))

}

function draw() {
  for (var ball in this.balls) {
    ball.drawCircle();
  }
}

this.Ball = function(x, y, r) {
  console.log("Ball created");
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;

  this.drawCircle = function (){
    ellipse(x, y, r);
  }

}
```

The problem is that i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ball.drawCircle is not a function
    at draw (sketch.js:12)
    at e.d.redraw (p5.min.js:6)
    at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:4)
    at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:4)
    at new e (p5.min.js:5)
    at e (p5.min.js:4)
```

So it should call the drawcircle funtion for every ball in the balls array, however it says that drawCircle is not a function. The problem is that I just don't understand why. I have tried using var drawCircle instead of this.drawCirle, I also tried using funcion drawCircle.

Kind regards.

p.s. this code uses p5.js, the Ball created log is executed

Comment: draw() is a function added by p5js, it gets called every frame

Comment: in the loop : `for (var ball in this.balls)`, `ball` is an integer ( the index ), try `for (var ball of this.balls) `, or keep the `in` and replace `ball.drawCircle();` with `this.balls[ball].drawCircle();`

Comment: This has nothing todo with scope or context, its a syntax error `for..in` instead of `for..of`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a class so you don't have issues with `this` context:

```
function Ball(x, y, r) {
  console.log("Ball created");
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
}

Ball.prototype.drawCircle = function() {
  ellipse(x, y, r);
};
```

Or in ES6:

```
class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    console.log("Ball created");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }
  drawCircle() {
    ellipse(x, y, r);
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this (apart from the ES6 part) functionally do the same thing? It feels like this would have the same issues. Happy to be corrected. I didn't downvote by the way.

Comment: With the first option i still got the error, but the second one totally worked! thanks! (i cant accept an answer yet)

Comment: Yes, both do the same thing. Its just syntax.